# Position Relative Divs, Containing Absolute Divs Below Each Other

Tags: html, css

I have multiple relative positioned divs, which contain 3 absolute positioned divs each. Currently, they are shown to overlap each other and not below.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1m8pr6vy/)

How do I position them below one another?

Each parent div is like below.

`<html>`

```
  <div style="background: #F2F2F2; padding: 10px; border-radius: 50px; position: absolute; width: calc(100% - 30px); height: 15px;">

  </div>

  <div style="background: #2CA2B7; padding: 10px; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; position: absolute; width: 20%; height: 15px;">

    Item1

  </div>

  <div style="background: #D0CECE; padding: 10px; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; right: 0%; position: absolute; width: 60%; height: 15px;">

    Name1

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: your code is invalid or probably badly formatted. For instance, you have one extra closing div

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your parent divs all have the height = 0, because all theirs children are absolute positioned, so they don't occupy any space.

A solution would be to add height to the parent divs... 
or even better to make them `display: flex` and remove the absolute positioning from the children.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't really understand what you are trying to do.
but you can give the div's with absolute position a specific top - like this

```
  <div style="background: #F2F2F2; padding: 10px; border-radius: 50px; position: absolute; width: calc(100% - 30px); height: 15px;">

  </div>

  <div style="background: #2CA2B7; padding: 10px; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; position: absolute; width: 20%; top: 50px; height: 15px;">

    Item1

  </div>

  <div style="background: #D0CECE; padding: 10px; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; right: 0%; position: absolute; width: 60%; top: 100px; height: 15px;">

    Name1

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display each div on a separate line and below each other, you should not use `position: absolute;`.
You could use `margin-top: 15px` to separate them from each other.
In order to use `position: absolute;` you need to define at least one of top, left, bottom or right.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding margin-bottom:50px in increments of +50px to each relative div.

Such as below.

```
<div style="position: relative; margin-bottom:150px;" class="projectSidebarSelectedProjectInformation-Stats">
```

Comment: It would be better to make them display: flex and remove absolute positioning from the children..